# Who can help me with Beacon data?

Tags: validators, beacon-chain

How can I get Beacon node data, like the beacon smart contract balance or balance of validators? Renat Ghoste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the balance of beacon smart contract, one can simply do an `eth_getBalance` RPC call, and to get the balance of a validator, one can use `validator_balances` call of the Beacon REST API.

For `eth_getBalance`, one can use any RPC provider to get the balance but to get the validator address using the `validator_balances` call of the Beacon REST API we'll need [QuickNode](https://quicknode.com/) as most of the other providers do not have beacon chain data. So it's better to use QuickNode for both operations but may depend on your choice.

To get the **balance of the Beacon smart contract** - here's an example in ethers v6

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");
(async () => {
  const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider("RPC_URL_HERE");
  const balance = await provider.getBalance(
    "0x00000000219ab540356cBB839Cbe05303d7705Fa",
    "latest"
  );
  console.log(ethers.formatEther(balance));
})();
```

To get the **balance of a validator** - here's an example in vanilla JavaScript

```js
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("accept", "application/json");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("QUICKNODE_RPC_URL_HEREeth/v1/beacon/states/head/validator_balances?id=0xb8309891538bca2c1cb416a0a60378185ea705f665b8cf7e60b4b22380145bc611fb711062a835bf599b86d04e0d449a", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```